# How to decrease the size of a div in IE alone?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I am working on an application where the div height is 385px and its working fine with all the browsers except for IE.

Comment: pls show that screenshot or code....

Answer (score 1):

here is a javascript sample how you could do it:

```
var browsername = navigator.appName;
var yourdiv = document.getElementById("yourdivID");

if (browsername == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
 yourdiv.style.height = "200px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but I need a css fix.